# How to clear Azure Storage Emulator Data from command line?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, powershell, azure-storage-emulator

My solution is using Azure Emulator. I would like to clear the Azure Storage Emulator **Blobs**, **Queues** and **Tables** without having to perform manual actions. I need to be able to do it from command line, preferably PowerShell.

Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2015, Azure-node:

[image]

AzureStorageEmulator.exe help returns the following commands:

- AzureStorageEmulator.exe init: Initialize the emulator database and configuration.
- AzureStorageEmulator.exe start: Start the emulator.
- AzureStorageEmulator.exe stop: Stop the emulator.
- AzureStorageEmulator.exe status: Get current emulator status.
- AzureStorageEmulator.exe clear: Delete all data in the emulator.
- AzureStorageEmulator.exe help [command]: Show general or command-specific help.

However when trying out "clear" the following is returned:

> The following services have been succesfully cleared of user data:
>   None

Answer (score 82):

```sh
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator
.\AzureStorageEmulator.exe clear all
```

Comment: this hangs for me! anyone have any ideas how to do this manually?

Comment: The docs for the Storage Emulator command line tool are at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#storage-emulator-command-line-tool-reference

Comment: @JohnNicholas - Stop the emulator. Then delete the AzureStorageEmulatorDbXXX.mdf / ldf files in your windows home directory.

Comment: For people suspecting a hang: it took a long time to run for me, several minutes.

Answer (score 16):

**Visual Studio 2022 and Azurite**

- it will not use SQL Server like Legacy Storage Simulator and all the related data is stored as large JSON files in the following folder.

**%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\Azurite**

or maybe

**%userprofile%\AppData\Local\.vstools\Azurite**

[image: Azurite Emulator default location]

- you will see  [Azurite](https://github.com/Azure/Azurite)  services starting up in Visual Studio Service Dependencies Window when you open VS with any project that needs this
  [image]
- Azure Storage Explorer Will automatically connect to this new emulator VIA REST-API and if you using Legacy Emulator and new emulator at the same time you are working with different data sets
- it seems that Azurite currently has no explicit stop and clear command (3.14.3) and if you cannot delete these folders, just close both Visual Studio and Storage Explorer and try again.
- see also related note on official note in azurite github ([link](https://github.com/Azure/Azurite/blob/main/README.md#workspace-structure))

> Note. Delete above files and folders and restart Azurite to clean up
> Azurite. It will remove all data stored in Azurite!!

---

check always the **Output** -> **Service Dependencies** to find the correct location. Recently the location is changed to the following folder

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\.vstools\azurite
```

---

**Visual Studio 2019 and deprecated Azure Storage Emulator**

Running "AzureStorageEmulator.exe clear all" & "init" command usually hangs (or may take too much time)

solution: you can go to user folder (%userprofile%) usually in the following address and **delete** existing **AzureStorageEmulatorDb510.mdf** and ldf files.(last suffix 510 stands for version 5.10 of emulator)

```
C:\Users\[YOUR_USER] or %userprofile%
```

if you can not delete them you because they are locked, stop Azure Storage Emulator by running *AzureStorageEmulator.exe stop* and try again or simply by **shutting** it down from its icon  in system tray

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach if you are using Azurite & VS2022+ is to use VSCode [Durable Functions Monitor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DurableFunctionsMonitor.durablefunctionsmonitor) extension to delete the hub in the emulator.

I found Purge and Clean operations (from VSCode ext.) failed against Azurite both when I ran from VS2022 or using docker. They work for me when I am using real Azure storage. This eliminates the annoyance of having to quit VS before you can delete the files.

Deleting the hub in VSCode [Durable Functions Monitor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DurableFunctionsMonitor.durablefunctionsmonitor) is by far the quickest way I have found so far to reset everything before another debug run.

Comment: Those purge methods are useless.